# Remove the zero line from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to avoid plotting lines beyond the first and last zero to avoid this overlap.  Please note that this is just a toy data of a much bigger data set and that solution to filter 0s does not work in this case.

```
dta <- 
data.frame(grp = c(rep("a",10), rep("b",10),rep("c",10)),
  lines = c(rep(seq(1,10,1),3)),
           vc =  c(c(0,0,0,0,.3,.3,.1, 0,0,0),
                   c(.1,.3,.3,.3,.1, 0,0,0,0,0),
                   c(0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0)))
            
            
            dta %>% 
          ggplot(aes(lines, vc, color = grp))+
          geom_line()+
          scale_x_continuous(
            breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)
          )+
      scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(-0.01, 1),
        breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)
      )
```

[image]
Any ideas on how to remove these lines, please? For example, the blue line should stop at x=6.
If I set 0 to `NA` lines do not go down to the x-axis.

```
dta %>% 
  mutate(vc = ifelse(vc==0, NA, vc)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lines, vc, color = grp))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-0.01, 1),
    breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)
  )
```

[image]
I need the blue line to go down to the x-axis and then stop. This goes for all other lines.

Comment: Can you specify what the "first" and "last" zero is when avoiding the overlap.  The answer below can be achieved by using the fact that ggplot does not plot NAs. If you set your zeros to NA. Oviously, ggplot plots your data. . This means, if you do not want to have the blue line overlaying the red as of x = 8, you need to remove the data points (or set them NA).

Comment: better? Ths is a big data set and it is not feasible for me to remove it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dta %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(across(-lines,
                ~ ifelse(lag(.) == 0 & . == 0 & lead(.) == 0, NA, .))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lines, vc, color = grp)) +
  geom_line()
```

Produces this plot:

[image: plot without zeros]

Answer (score 1):

This solution is kind of verbose but does what you need I believe. It can be applied to a grouped data frame. For each group, given a column name as input, it trims away rows at the beginning and end where that column is equal to zero... but importantly it retains a zero at the beginning and end.

#### function definition

The function uses tidy evaluation for the column name by which to trim the data frame. The statements with `which` find runs of zeroes at the beginning and end, if present, and retain the last zero before the nonzero entries and the first one after them.

```
trim_zero <- function(data, column) {
  x0 <- pull(data, {{ column }}) == 0
  beginning_0 <- max(which(x0)[which(x0) < min(which(!x0))], 1)
  ending_0 <- min(which(x0)[which(x0) > max(which(!x0))], length(x0))
  
  data[beginning_0:ending_0, ]
  
}
```

#### applying the function to your data

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

dta_trimmed <- dta %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  group_modify(~ trim_zero(., vc)) 

ggplot(dta_trimmed, aes(lines, vc, color = grp))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)
  )+
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-0.01, 1),
    breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Works on toy data but made problems with variables whih are 0 all along in some of factes in bigger data

Answer (score -1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

dta <- 
  data.frame(grp = c(rep("a",10), rep("b",10)),
             lines = c(rep(seq(1,10,1),2)),
             vc =  c(c(0,0,0,0,.3,.3,.1, 0,0,0),
                     c(.1,.3,.3,.3,.1, 0,0,0,0,0)))


dta %>%
  filter(vc > 0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lines, vc, color = grp))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Not really what I need